# Why my wordpress site URL does not begin with my domain?

Tags: urls, domain

I'm hosting a web app on **my-app.pro**, and it's the main domain for the hosting. The containing folder is */home/my-app.pro/www*.

I'm using a framework, and it does the rewriting job, so all my pages are reachable at **my-app.pro/pages-names/etc**

Now I'm publishing another website, a wordpress one, with the *Divi Theme*, on the same hosting. I put it in this folder */home/my-app.pro/www/my-site.com/www*.

The hosting is configured to reach the good folder when **my-site.com** is typed as an URL.

But all my wordpress site's pages have an URL like **my-app.pro/my-site.com/www/my-page**, and not **my-site.com/my-page** as needed (except for the main page, which is working).

How do I change this? Is it in the database directly? Or is it a configuration issue?

Comment: What do you have for "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" in Settings, General? Why did you put this site inside the my-app.pro/www folder and not some parallel folder that you can add to your web server configuration? Which web server are you using?

Comment: In the Settings, the adresses are **my-app.pro/my-site.com/www**. I decided to put it in a different folder to avoid confusion, and to have a better structure for future sites hosting. It's an Apache 2.4 server

Comment: Does the site come up when you go to my-site.com and if so, is it also redirected to my-app.pro/my-site.com/www?

Comment: Is your question connected with WordPress in any way? Server, theme, plugins, but not WordPress.

Comment: "In the Settings, the adresses are my-app.pro/my-site.com/www" - this is what WordPress is using. These are the URLs not the paths on disk. If your site is hosted at my-site.com then this should just be `https://my-site.com` I think?

Comment: Yes, *my-site.com* is displayed, and the home icon redirects to *my-app.pro/my-site.com/www*, which is the same page, and is also displayed. I tried to change in the Settings the 2 URL, puting *my-site.com*, but this causes a 404 error for all the other pages than *my-site.com*.

Comment: @BenoitPoux did you consider a multisite install? That way you can have 1 install that serves multiple sites. To serve a WP site from a different domain you'll need custom Apache VHosts to map it to that folder, you can't just put it in a subfolder and tell it that the URL is different, that won't work

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Your reply sounds like the good way to search for. I found tutorials to change my site to a multisite, and for mapping. But unfortunately, after configuring multisite as it's teached, I had a 'no connection to the database' error, and could not find where it came from. Each step forward causes 2 steps backwards, it's frustrating. I give up. Thanks for trying to help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues in the past, hosting two different sites with two domains on one host. Here are the two things that have helped me:

**Update WordPress Settings**

In the WordPress Admin Dashboard, go to Settings > General.

You'll notice that there's the *WordPress Address (URL)* and the *Site Address (URL)*. These control where WordPress views the files and the address that the site is viewed at. Double check these. If they are not what you want, then try changing them.

**Update Host Settings**

Sometimes, to have two different domains on one host you'll have to configure an "Add-on" domain with your host. This usually involves specifying the folder for the second domain, and the problem should be fixed.

**If that doesn't work**

Here's the link to WordPress.org on what they recommend. Their solution involves changing the configuration files.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/

Comment: I tried to change the addresses, it causes the site to be unfunctionnal, or to have 404 error on pages. The only change that works, is the Site Address, but it doesn't change anything for the URL, because **my-site.com** was already working. The host settings update is not necessary, it's already in place and it works to reach **my-site.com**. Then, the link you gave is interesting, but it says I have to put the index.php file from wordpress to the root and to change some code lines, but I already have an index.php file in this folder, for the **my-app.pro** site. It involves too much changes.